# Maximize a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Please help me how to deal with maximization of functional like this:

$$F\{a(s)\} = \int\limits_0^t \left( g(a(s)) - \alpha\, v(s)^2 \right) ds, \ a(s) \in \left[0, \infty\right)$$

where $g(x) = x e^{-x}$ , $\alpha=\mathrm{const}$, and
$\displaystyle v(t) = \int\limits_0^t a(s) ds$

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try to use calculus of variation. Check [Euler–Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal It was the first thing I've tried. I don't undestand how to deal with $v(t)^2$.

Comment: Could you please clarify the definition of your functional? I think that the integral is from $0$ to $\infty$. Also, waht is the precise definition of $v(t)$. Is $v(t)=\int_0^t a(s)ds$?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @centuri0n even now your question is unclear, because of upper limit in the integral in the definition of $F$

Comment: @Norbert, OK, fixed.

Comment: @centuri0n, so you mean that $t$ is fixed and $F$ sends $a$ to some  real number. Right?

Comment: @Norbert Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how to deal with $v^2$

Reformulate the problem in terms of $v$. That is, you seek the maximum of 
$$F\{v\} = \int\limits_0^t \left( g(v'(s)) - \alpha\, v(s)^2 \right) ds, \ a(s) \in \left[0, \infty\right) \tag1$$
over increasing differentiable functions $v$ with $v(0)=0$. The Euler-Lagrange equation for (2) is easy to state: 
$$
-\frac{d}{ds}(g'(v'(s))) -2\alpha v(s)\equiv 0 \tag2 
$$
Since $g''(x)=(x-2)e^{-x}$, the equation (2) becomes
$$
(2-v'(s))e^{-v'(s)}v''(s) -2\alpha v(s)\equiv 0 \tag3 
$$
I wouldn't expect an explicit solution of (3), but a numeric solution should not be hard to obtain.

Comment: Any chance for assistance here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066495/minimization-of-variational-total-variation-tv-deblurring